# Screen layout with python scripting possible

Tags: python, interface

Is it possible to make layout changes in the interface of blender?

What I want to do:
My aim is to code an operator which removes all unnessesary areas or regions like the 'HEADER' of some areas or the 'INFO' area.

I have taken a look into

```
# areas[0] is 'PROPERTIES'
# regions[0] is 'HEADER'
bpy.data.screens['Scripting'].areas[0].regions[0].heigth = 0
```

but it ends with

```
AttributeError: bpy_struct: attribute "height" from "Region" is read-only
```

Is there a way to get my values into these variables?

Comment: I may not understand your question. If you have the goal of clearing up the workspace for your personal use ....
Blender has put some effort into keystrokes for a flexible screen layout.
You can have many different screen layouts ... some are already provided.
You can create your own.
By using keystroke ............ control down arrow ........... will maximize a given window. Same keystroke to restore.
You can also duplicate the entire blender screen and move it to a second physical monitor.

Comment: Is there any reason you want to use python to do this? All of this can be done using the GUI..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, currently the screen layout/geometry is read-only from Python's perspective.

(Can only be edited via interactive operators).

You can:

- Change space types.
- Change screens.
- Change scenes.

But not resize spaces/regions.

Comment: Has this changed in 2.8?